# How to find the x , y values of two point parallel to a line

Tags: linear-algebra

In the attached image.

[image]

The values of Points , P1 , P2 , P3 and P4 are known.

How can we get the values  of Q1 and Q2 which are parallel to points P3 , P4.

Comment: For $Q1$: for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a(P3-P4)$ has the same direction as the parallel line, and $bP1 + (1-b)P2$ is a point collinear with $P1$ and $P3$. This form an equation for the two unknowns:

$$P2+a(P3-P4) = bP1 + (1-b)P2\quad (=Q1)$$

Comment: @peterwhy what are the values a and b in the given equation.

Comment: As you know $P1$ to $P4$, the $a$ and $b$ are up to you to solve.

Comment: @peterwhy a = P3 - P4 and b = P3 - P1 , is this correct.

Comment: $a,b\in\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = (u_x, u_y) =  P_3 - P_4 $ and let $ v $ be perpedicular to $u$, i.e.

$ v = (-u_y, u_x) $

Now compute $ t = \dfrac{ (P_1 - P_2) \cdot v }{ (P_1 - P_3) \cdot v } $

Then

$ Q_1 = P_1 + t (P_3 - P_1) $

$ Q_2 = P_1 + t (P_4 - P_1) $

The image shows the points $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$ in blue and $Q_1$ an $Q_2$ in red

[image]

Comment: is t a scalar component ?

Comment: $t $ is the ratio of the height of the small triangle to the height of the large triangle, where the base of the small triangle is $Q_1 Q_2$ and the base of the large triangle is $P_3 P_4$

Comment: Y Hajjir i am not able to get the correct values , this is how i am calculation t

Comment: In the formula for $t$, both the numerator and denominator are dot products the respective vectors.

Comment: Y Hajjir Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: My pleasure ...